# Texture2D.Load works in HLSL fragment shader, but not in vertex shader

Tags: textures, hlsl, vertex-shader

The documentation claims it's supported from vs_4_0 and higher [ [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-to-load) ] (I'm using vs_5_0), but all values return (0, 0, 0, 0). Is there anything I'm missing?

```
Texture2D view0 : register(t0);

SamplerState MeshTextureSampler: register(s0) {
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

cbuffer InputData : register(b0) {
    uint width;
    uint height;
}

struct VertexInputType {
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexOutputType {
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertexOutputType VShader(VertexInputType input) {
    VertexOutputType output;
    output.position = input.position;
    output.tex = input.tex;
    output.color = view0.Load(int3(output.tex.x * width, output.tex.y * height, 0));

    return output;
}

float4 PShader(VertexOutputType input) : SV_TARGET
{
    //DOES NOT WORK
    return input.color; 

    //WORKS
    return float4(view0.Load(int3(input.tex.x * width, input.tex.y * height, 0)).rgb, 1); 
}
```

Comment: What happens if you updated your vs like so:
`output.color = view0.Load(int3(input.tex.x * width, input.tex.y * height, 0));`

Even though what you're doing is functionally equivalent, I've run into strange issues in the past which were resolved by using inputs rather than outputs that are initialised from input data

Comment: It's the same result, but I changed it to exclude any issues there. Thank you!

Comment: I was just investingating this problem myself on D3D10, where I had the same symptoms.  On just trying things I fixed it by setting the texture on the pixel shader instead, even though the load is occurring in the vertex shader.  Perhaps this would help someone else with the same problem.